# How to give runtime value in @test.enabled attribute

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations, automated-tests, testng

I am working with selenium webdriver with TestNG in java.

For executing test suite I want to add runtime value in `@Test(enabled=true/false)`.
But enabled attribute accepts only constants (true/false) before start execution.

Is there any way to control `@Test` methods to decide whether to execute or not?

Comment: Runtime value in the sense? What value are you trying to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thanks for your efforts, but please find attached link which ll help you to achieve what I want to](http://test-this.ro/selenium-testng-customizing-tests-at-runtime-with-iannotationtransformer/)

You have to override @test method by IAnnotationTransformer interface.

Thanks 
Dhaval

Comment: Right, `IAnnotationTransformer` is the best solution! To close the question, you should accept your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dhaval, I think you are thinking this the wrong way; looking at what you want to achieve. Of course you can have a global scoped var, something like hasTheScriptReachedAPointToIssueSessionID? But in your case, you probably want to look at testng method dependencies (@Test annotations are methods/test steps in your testClass). So here is an example:

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void login(){

//do the login stuff
}


@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods="login")
public void clickAccountBtn(){      

//go to account 
}


@Test (priority=3, dependsOnMethods="clickAccountBtn")
public void editPassword() {            

//edit pass
}
```

As you can see there are 2 subjects here to help you regulate your test flow. Priorities and dependencies. Priorities help testNG to regulate execution order (what first, what last) whilst dependencies help you fail-fast (i.e if you fail to login skip the rest steps as there is no point trying to clickOnTheAccountButton). Hope this makes sense, let me know if it does not.

You can find more here:
[TestNG Doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Best of luck

Comment: Yes your way is correct and usefull but in my case i want to achieve like ..Suppose initially I run test suite with 10 test case and it fail at 5th test case so when i run test suite again it should start executing the test from 6th one .. so for me i guess my solution is usefull

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one alternative way to decide weather you want to execute a method or not

- in your `testing.xml` you can use `<exclude>`tag  see below example

  ```
  <test name="sample_Test" >
      <classes>
          <class name="ClassOneTest">
           <methods>
                <exclude name="methodOne" />
           </methods>
          </class>
          <class name="ClassTwoTest"/>
      </classes>
  </test>
  ```